# How to force transition animation for properties not yet defined on the element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transition

I have this code:

```js
    var c = document.getElementById('container');

    function expand() {
        c.style.maxHeight = ~~(Math.random() * 50 + 50) + 'px'; // it can be any value
        // Since the value is dynamic, static solutions (like CSS Animations) are not allowed
    }

    function shrink() {
        c.style.maxHeight = '0px';
    }
```

```css
    .container {
        transition: max-height 1s ease;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">Hello, World!<br />Hello, World!<br />Hello, World!<br />Hello, World!<br />Hello, World!<br /></div>

<input type="button" onclick="expand()" value="Expand" />
<input type="button" onclick="shrink()" value="Shrink" />
```

When I click the "Shrink" button, the container instantly goes to 0px height.
Since the property "maxHeight" is not set yet, the animation hasn't both start/end parameters to perform the transition.
After I click either button, the animation runs normally.

I can bypass this issue presetting the property if it's not set yet, but I need to use setTimeout and lambda functions, what is way overcomplicated to the simplicity I'm looking for.

Also, I cannot add the style='maxheight=xxx' property on each element because this function manages elements on third party code, which I cannot alter.

So, how can I properly perform this animation?

Comment: And what is stopping you from applying it via your stylesheet, by adding it to the `.container` rule?

Comment: I cannot use CSS Animations neither static values. The maxHeight property can have any value each time its called.

Comment: Well then you should actually make that clear inside your question, that you need to _determine_ this value dynamically first. When you show example code with a hard-coded value like `100px`, that is not really clear.

Comment: I agree. I already edited the question to make it clear. Thanks for pointing this up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [force a reflow](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) right after you set the initial value, and right before you trigger the change:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('container');

function expand() {
  c.style.maxHeight = ~~(Math.random() * 50 + 50) + 'px'; // it can be any value
}

function shrink() {
  c.style.maxHeight = c.offsetHeight + "px";
  c.offsetHeight; // force reflow
  c.style.maxHeight = '0px';
}
```

```css
.container {
  transition: max-height 1s ease;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">Hello, World!<br />Hello, World!<br />Hello, World!<br />Hello, World!<br />Hello, World!<br /></div>

<input type="button" onclick="expand()" value="Expand" />
<input type="button" onclick="shrink()" value="Shrink" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The default value for `max-height` is `none`, you need to set a default value for it whatever with (CSS or JS), so the shrink works fine for the first time.

```js
var c = document.getElementById('container');
// With js
// c.style.maxHeight = '100px';

    function expand() {
        c.style.maxHeight = '100px';
    }

    function shrink() {
        c.style.maxHeight = '0px';
    }
```

```css
.container {
        transition: max-height 1s ease;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">Hello, World!<br />Hello, World!<br />Hello, World!<br />Hello, World!<br />Hello, World!<br /></div>

<input type="button" onclick="expand()" value="Expand" />
<input type="button" onclick="shrink()" value="Shrink" />
```